# A java project runs well from the command line, but it throws an exception when run from NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

A Java NetBeans project runs successfully from from the java command line.
However, when I try to run it in NetBeans I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: lost_in_euroland.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1179)
    at projtest.ProjTest.main(ProjTest.java:27)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Perhaps the audio files are not at the right place. If it is so where they are to be placed?

Comment: file location is your java class 146 is missing

Comment: Try to change the path of `lost_in_euroland.wav`. Add the full path or a gettable path, Or just copy the file in the src folder where your java file is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `lost_in_euroland.wav` not found which is at line `(FileInputStream.java:146)`
its is because Netbean could not found the file specify. Try to test your path again and retry.

**Suggestions:**

In Netbeans when you read any file it start from `Project` path like `C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyCurrentProject`.
create a new folder or place your `lost_in_euroland.wav` file in project folder like

`C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyCurrentProject\lost_in_euroland.wav`

**OR**

`C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyCurrentProject\sound\lost_in_euroland.wav`

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation for this error is that your filepath for `lost_in_euroland.wav`is incorrect. When running a program from the command line, the directory is defaulted to where you opened the shell from, whereas NetBeans (or any IDE, for that matter) does not default to a specified directory (perhaps `C:/`)

Instead of `lost_in_euroland.wav`, try to use the absolute filepath, which might look like `C://Users//<Your Username>//Desktop//lost_in_euroland.wav` (notice the double slashes to ensure that the filepath is correct in Netbeans - due to Java escape sequences).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Manan, your concise hint has given me some good understanding of the subject, and  my problem is solved. Again thanks.